# How to stretch gradient background to fit the page?

Tags: css, background-image

I have two backgrounds on website, one which is gradient and on it some transparent repeating pattern.

```
    html{
         background-color:rgb(57,57,57);
         background-image: url("../repeating-tansparent-pattern.png"), url("../gradient-background.jpg");
}
```

The gradient background is only 1080px height. I'd like to stretch it to fit 1800px and also preserve the repeating pattern. Stretching one background is easy,but how to deal with these two??

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkpey91a/

Comment: could you please create a JSFiddle?

Comment: use `background-size:cover`

Comment: It's not the right pattern,but it will suffice. http://jsfiddle.net/jkpey91a/

Comment: @Gunaseelan not a duplicate, this is specifically about making 2 backgrounds behave differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you can specify 2 comma-separated backgrounds, you can do the same for all other `background-` properties. Adding this:

```
background-size:auto,cover;
background-position:top left, center;
```

Will yield [the intended result](http://jsfiddle.net/jkpey91a/1/).

Want the gradient to fill the viewport statically, and the flakes to scroll? Easy:

```
background-attachment:scroll,fixed;
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jkpey91a/2/).

Having said all this, for compatibility it is of course much easier to just put the gradient on `html` and the flakes on `body`, but with CSS3 it's all possible just fine what you want.